# modify the table from its own trigger in Mysql- PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm using Mysql in phpMyAdmin,where i have to delete a entry from tableA if i insert a row with same primary key.I thought to do it in trigger of tableA BEFORE INSERT
For Ex,
if the tableA contains

```
1 Hai Hello
```

here 1 is the primary key

And now if i insert a row `1 Bye Hello` then the trigger BEFORE INSERT will delete the old entry and then the new row (2nd) will be inserted. But Mysql has restriction of not being able to update a table inside a trigger defined for that same table.

It gives the error

> #1442 - Can't update table 'tableA' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger.

So i changed my way, i called a procedure from trigger BEFORE INSERT of tableA and in that procedure i do the task what i thought to do in trigger. But unfortunately i'm getting the same error.
In trigger BEFORE INSERT i simply called the procedure as

```
CALL proce1(new.Reg_No);
```

In procedure i have done this

```
DECLARE toup integer;
    select count(*) into toup from tableA where Reg_No=reg;/*Here Reg_No is primary key */
        if toup > 0 then
     delete from tableA where Reg_No=reg;
    end if;
```

Need some other Idea to achieve this. Help Me.....

Comment: why are you deleting? are you trying to replace the old data or really delete the record?

Comment: @Mike I want to delete the old record and insert new one. I just insert the new values from .csv file here old values cannot be updated and so i thought to delete it before the insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like to use triggers so much because they are hard to manage somethimes. Also they will cause you a downgrade in performance. I am not against trigger as they can be handy in some cases.

In your case have you though of using `REPLACE(....)` or `INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or even `INSERT INTO IGNORE .....`

`REPLACE(....)` will delete a record if a record is found and insert a new one with the same ID.

`INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will allow you to override existing field if a duplicate is found.

`INSERT INTO IGNORE .....` will allow you to ignore the new inserted row if one already exists

Since you mentioned in the comments that you are importing records from a file, then try to use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) logic which will allow you to `REPLACE` field on duplicate

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'x3export.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE x3export
```

Comment: sorry i cant use replace query since i need to insert the values from .csv file. i just directly imported it.

Comment: How are you importing the data? can't you insert into ignore?

Comment: Actually on importing csv file mysql automatically executes only the normal `INSERT...` query. Is there any way to change this automatic query to REPLACE or any other you said above

Comment: Actually REPLACE will give the answer if i write it explicitly.

Comment: How are you importing the data?

Comment: there is an option in phpMyAdmin(Xampp) as 'import' by clicking this we can browse a csv or sql file and import the data. this will inserts the values in the file to the table.

Comment: please check my updated answer for a better way to import data and solve your problem

Comment: it only inserts a single row with reg.no column only and other cols left blank

Comment: Got it.... Thank you so much. :) i used the syntax as for .csv file `LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/c.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE tableA FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'`